# Add Search button in place of enter button Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone 8 app,Want to add button with text Search(In place of Enter Button) while click on search textbox jsut like in Store search it shows white button in place of Enter button on keyboard.

Comment: Do you mean change the enter button on the soft keyboard to display 'search' instead?

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got good alternative...

```
        InputScope inputScope = new InputScope();
        InputScopeName inputScopeName = new InputScopeName();
        inputScopeName.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Search;
        inputScope.Names.Add(inputScopeName);
        TextBox11.InputScope = inputScope;
```

Answer (score 2):

To follow the standards you really only should set the InputScope to search. Not a "search" text, but the Windows Phone standard search keyboard.

```
<TextBox InputScope="Search" />
```